# D3 adding dots to multiple stacked line charts

Tags: javascript, jquery, csv, d3.js

I'm creating multiple line-graphs that are stacked by "symbol" from a csv-file.

This is how the csv looks-like:

```
symbol,date,price
Agency,2015/5/6,33
Agency,2015/5/7,29
Agency,2015/5/8,32
test,2015/5/6,23
test,2015/5/7,19
test,2015/5/8,22
example,2015/5/6,43
example,2015/5/7,49
example,2015/5/8,42
```

So for each symbol contained in the csv-file a separate graph gets drawn. This all works fine so far.

But I'm struggling to add dots to each line.

This is the part that's creating the dots (line 142 - 148 in [my fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/doyL1L0p/1/)):

```
var circles = svg.selectAll("dot")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("circle")
        .attr("r", 2)
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.date); })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.price); })
        .style("fill", "black");
```

But this code creates the dots populated by the values of the **last "symbol"** off the csv and not **separate for each "symbol"**.

I researched a lot here on stackoverflow, but none of the solutions or hints I found worked for me.

In this example http://jsbin.com/isuris/1/edit?html,output I found this part:

```
// add circles
pathContainers.selectAll('circle')
.data(function (d) { return d; })
.enter().append('circle')
.attr('cx', function (d) { return xScale(d.x); })
.attr('cy', function (d) { return yScale(d.y); })
.attr('r', 3);
```

So I tried to change line 143 of my fiddle http://fiddle.jshell.net/doyL1L0p/1/ like this:

```
.data(function (d) { return d; })
```

But this didn't work, the "wrong" dots disappear.

So I tried this:

```
.data(function (d) { return d.key; })
```

because the separate "symbol"-value gets displayed by using "d.key". But know I get this error in the console:

```
Unexpected value NaN for attribute cx
Unexpected value NaN for attribute cy
```

Then I tried to alter lines 146 and 147:

```
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.date); })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.price); })
```

but without success.

I tried many other posted "solutions" off stackoverflow and others I found in the web, but all without success again.

Can anyone please give me a hint on how to solve this?

Heres the fiddle again:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/doyL1L0p/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on some editing of your fiddle, it seems that they ARE actually being displayed... but they're out of range of the canvas. 
If you look at the outcome [here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/doyL1L0p/5/), you can see that the newly added point near the top is displayed, on all of the graphs.

I'll see if I can work on a proper fix, because obviously this is not the desired behaviour.

**UPDATE**

It looks like the problem is that you aren't updating your domain when you display your dots, so they are using the last domain which was set (hence why only last show normally). In addition, you are displaying dots for the entire data set on each graph (although most of them are outside the domain).

I would actually recommend trying to parse your data into an array for each unique symbol, it make things much more straightforward for you. For example, you could simply set the domain using `d3.extent`.

**SUMMARY**

A couple of solutions spring to mind:

1. Setting up separate axes/domains per graph.
2. Putting your dots into a g element per symbol, then adding data to them via a nested selection.

[This](http://fiddle.jshell.net/doyL1L0p/32/) works, but you really should read up a bit more on (nested) selections. Ideally, you would probably want to separately generate each graph, out of scope of the others. This solution is badly designed, but hopefully it should help to give you an idea of how your code is working.

Comment: thx Roland for your post...I need a day or two to get back to this, then I will check what you've posted....so far I don't understand what you're meaning, but I need to do some research on your tipps and hope to get it sorted out somehow! I'm struggling for about a week on this now, must be achievable ;) so thanks and I'll get back to you on here!

Comment: another short comment...one thing I don't understand is how in my original fiddle on lines 132-139 the "symbol"-value gets displayed for each graph separately without any "forEach" or something similar. As well as the graphs, that get displayed without something like that...hm...I guess I need to read the pdf-book from start. Will get back to you...

Comment: @EMEm The code on lines 132-139 automagically acts on each of the data items bound with svg.data(...), in the function(d){} you are passing each of these elements as d. Also, if you are using chrome, it might be a good idea to right click on your page, inspect elements, and go to the sources tab. 
You can add breakpoints that help you get a better idea of what your code does there, if you find the source where your js is.

Comment: Hello again Roland! I got back to this today and seems like I sorted it out...didn't see the link in your "**This** works"...by looking at this last fiddle you linked I sorted it out...thx a lot to you!